# Find Radius of hemisphere inside a square pyramid

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d, solid-geometry

You have a hemisphere that touches all faces of a square pyramid (except the base).

You are given the length of each side, as well as the height of the pyramid and asked to find the radius of the hemisphere inside.

For example, using length 15 and height 10. What's r?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. You should include in your question your own thoughts on the problem, information about what you have tried and any problems you encountered. For example, have you tried drawing a diagram, perhaps a side view of the pyramid with the hemisphere inside?

Comment: Yea I've tried different things, but in the end I feel like I need some kind of formulas to figure this out. I know the edge of the hemisphere touches the sides of the pyramid, so the diameter would be equal to the length of the pyramid at that point. Problem is figuring out where in the pyramid this point of contact is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use similar triangles and the Pythagorean Theorem.

[image: Pyramid Problem]